# How to concat values in different tables - mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I do not speak English, but I always try to learn. Sorry for bad interpretations.

I have a database with 2 tables. This tables are interconnected. See example:

```
table1

uniqueid,name,type,accountcode
9999999,test,incoming,1

table2

id,name,foo,bar
1, mobile call,foo,bar
```

In table one, the value accountcode is the same in table two id field. I would like execute a select and show this

```
table1

uniqueid,name,type,accountcode
9999999,test,incoming,**mobile call**
```

I'm try INNER JOIN, but the results did not go as expected.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Join between the two tables using [`Inner Join`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) with their appropriate relationships.
- In case of multi-table queries, it is a good practice to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/), for code disambiguation and readability.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  t1.uniqueid, 
  t1.name, 
  t1.type, 
  t2.name AS accountcode 
FROM 
  Table1 AS t1 
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.accountcode
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ask my post.  

I try this query, result is:  
`
mysql> SELECT    
    -> cdr.calldate,     
    -> cdr.billsec,     
    -> cdr.accountcode,    
    -> ccustos.nome AS accountcode    
    -> FROM    
    -> cdr AS t1    
    -> JOIN ccustos AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.accountcode;   
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cdr.calldate' in 'field list'`

Comment: @AndersonFreitas once you have aliased the table `cdr` to `t1`, you should now use the alias instead. Use `t1.calldate` and so on..

Comment: OMG!!

Sorry for not perceive this detail. I run again, executing changes and results is exactly what I wanted.

Thanks so much!